# Querying multiple domains for a computer object

Tags: c#, csv, active-directory

So I have some code to query multiple domains for a specific computer object and output the results to a csv.  Here is my code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string log = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\New.csv";

            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(log, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);

                var domains = File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\domains.csv");

                foreach (var line in domains)
                {
                    PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, line.ToString());
                    ComputerPrincipal query = new ComputerPrincipal(AD);
                    query.Name = "COMPNAME";

                    PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher();
                    search.QueryFilter = query;

                    ComputerPrincipal result = (ComputerPrincipal)search.FindOne();

                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(result.DistinguishedName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The domains.csv file contains all 10 of our domains.  What happens is `result` always shows up as `null`.  What am I missing?

EDIT: Sorry guys.  The code works fine.  It is the writer that is failing to create the CSV.

Comment: what happens when you actually step through the code setting breakpoints vs just running it.. ? can you show us what the contents of the actual .csv file look like.. ?

Comment: I just replaced the writer with a console write and it works fine.  Need to fix the writer.

Comment: also you need to replace this line `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` with 
`Console.WriteLine(ex.Mesage);`

Comment: Thanks MethodMan.  I will change that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no issue with the code.  It was my writer that was having the issue.  I replaced my writer with this

```
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(log))
```